# Creating ArrayList using java jni in android

Tags: java, android, c++

I want to create ArrayList by **using native code in android**, for that I have to allow all types of values to insert in list.

Following is my code:

```
std::vector<jobject> list;

extern "C"{

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_nativetestapp_NativeList_add(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jobject t) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"LOG","Set %d",t); //here it is printing some integer value like -1034567334
        list.push_back(t);
    }

    JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL     Java_com_example_nativetestapp_NativeList_removeByIndex(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint pos) {
        if (pos > list.size() - 1 || pos < 0)
            return false;
        return list.erase(list.begin() + pos) != NULL ? true : false;
    }

    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_nativetestapp_NativeList_size(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
        return list.size() == NULL ? 0 : list.size();
    }

    JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_nativetestapp_NativeList_get(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, int pos) {
        return list.at(pos);
    }

    JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_nativetestapp_NativeList_contains(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jobject t) {

        for (int var = 0; var < list.size(); var++) {
            if(t==list[var])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_nativetestapp_NativeList_remove(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jobject t) {
        for (int var = 0; var < list.size(); var++) {
            if(t==list[var]){
                list.erase(list.begin()+var);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

I have taken jobject in java jni to allow all types of values, but at the time of inserting in list, it is inserting reference like some number, not exact value.
And at the time of retrieval, it is returning reference only.
I tried so many ways, but it is not working.
Please help me to solve this issue!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to create a completely separe list type in native code, not trying to create/manage an actual Java `ArrayList` object instance, is this correct? If that is the case, why do you not want to instead manipulate the Java object via native code?

Comment: @zenzelezz can we use Java object in jni to pass as method param?

Comment: As long as the object (eg. `ArrayList`) is alive in Java, you can pass it through JNI and it will be a `jobject` in your native code, but unless you have a specific reason to use native code, I would stick to just using Java, since using JNI can be a little tedious.

Comment: @zenzelezz But i have to pass primitive type of data also is it possible through jobject?

Comment: If you mean primitives like `int` (etc), then I believe they can only be passed as `jint` (etc). But again, do you have a particular reason why you are using native code instead of just doing things in Java?

Comment: @zenzelezz Just to know whether it is possible or not that's it and thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Okay, that's reasonable enough. In that case I would suggest you try something slightly easier first, since what you are doing here is a little tricky. (Or read some more in-depth articles about how to use Java objects in/through JNI.)